# Shopify fulfill order no shipping

Tags: api, shopify

I'm struggling to find [docs](https://help.shopify.com/api/reference/shipping_and_fulfillment/fulfillment#create) on how to fulfill orders that require no shipping using the Shopify API. If anyone has any pointers please let me know.

Using order ID to fulfill the order with no shipping.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if you can do that by default. However, you can do this with webhooks/private app.

If you set a webhook on order creations and then your private app/server checks the payload to see if any order does not require shipping. Then you can make an API call to Shopify and fulfill that order assuming that does not required Shipping.

Comment: I know that much however, its once I know an order has been placed. I'm unsure of the payload that needs requested for fulfilling an order with no shipping.

Comment: Each line item has a parameter to check if required shipping or not.     `"requires_shipping": true,` [Source](https://help.shopify.com/api/reference/orders/order)